# Convert ASCII to Base64 then Binary with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, binary, base64

I'm trying to convert a text string `AAIA` to binary. This is how Salesforce manages dependent picklists.

I essentially need to go from **ascii** to **base64** to **binary**, but I think the **binary** needs to be bytes, not text.

Expected result is `AAIA` => `00000000 00000010 00000000`, which means 15th item in my other list controls this one. I can't figure out how to make this work in Node! Using the above mentioned values on [this](https://cryptii.com/pipes/base64-to-binary) site works, but no luck in Node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to convert a string to binary.
- You want to convert a string value of `AAIA` to `00000000 00000010 00000000`.
- You want to achieve this using Node.js.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

#### Sample script:

In this sample, there are the outputs of 3 patterns.

```
const str = "AAIA";

// Pattern 1
const buf = Buffer.from(str, 'base64');
console.log(buf); // <--- <Buffer 00 02 00>

// Pattern 2
const byteAr = Uint8Array.from(buf);
console.log(byteAr); // <--- Uint8Array [ 0, 2, 0 ]

// Pattern 3
const result = buf.reduce((s, e) => {
    const temp = e.toString(2);
    return s += "00000000".substring(temp.length) + temp + " ";
}, "");
console.log(result); // <--- 00000000 00000010 00000000
```

#### References:

- [Buffer.from(string[, encoding])](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_string_encoding)
- [Uint8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array)
- [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString)

If I misunderstood your question and these were not the results you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike! Pattern 3 is exactly what I'm after!

Comment: @McB Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.